# Few questions about hello world, instance variables and constructors (Java student)

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am a new java student and we are writing our first application.
I would like to clear up any confusion I have before I get to deep into these chapters.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    // Instance Variable?
    private String textToPrint;
    //main method     
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //Creating first object from our helloworld.java class 
        HelloWorld myObject = new HelloWorld("Hello, World!");
        // This is calling our method printText() created below, this knows to 
        myObject.printText();
    }
    // Constructor 
    public HelloWorld(String text)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        textToPrint = text;
    }
    // First Method
    public void printText()
    {
        System.out.print(textToPrint);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why do I need to place my `instance variable` above my `main method`?
        - Why is this not inside like a local variable?
2. We passed in `parameters` inside the `constructor (String Text)`, but
   why doesn't the bottom method have `parameters` inside of `printText()`?
3. Is the `constructor` needed in a `class` when defining objects of that
   `class`?
4. Check out my other `classes` when I remove the `constructor`, `object`.
   I'm very fuzzy on the point of a `constructor`, is still fuzzy to me
   about why we need to use it?

**Example:**
If I remove the `constructor` I can still pass in a local variable of "Test" into the parentheses of the `System.out.println()` method.

```
    public class Testing
    {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
           String test = "Hello world";
           System.out.println(test);
       }

    }
```

or simply

```
    public class Simple
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
```

Both above do not have an object or a method so I'm assuming the `constructor` is used to help define these?

Suggest some friendly tips for a soon to be java programmer.

Another edit for my fist comment below:
My current understanding of OOP.

1. Class = Doors
2. Creating an Object = Copy the class and ability to tweak the type of door, such as wooden or metal.
3. Method = Closing/Opening the door

What would a constructor do to help this above?

Comment: ooo Jenny, you should start to read a simple OOP topic and you will understand all about explicit contructors, and implicit constructors.

Comment: Topic from within stackoverflow? or from a programming book? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and this website was suggested to me :)

Comment: Edited main question to include my current understanding of OOP

Comment: follow Maroun Maroun's suggestions for first! Good Luck!

Comment: This question is very well written which is likely why it was so well recieved, however, in general it should be one post per question

Answer (score 2):

1. [Instance variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) are placed outside any class methods body. *Instance variables* can be used by all methods of a class (unless these methods are *static*)<sup>#</sup>. It's a personal preference whether to place them at top/bottom, but it's recommended by [Java style guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html#1852) to place them on top. So follow it.
2. `public void printText()` doesn't have to, because it only cares about the [member variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) `textToPrint`, which is accessible on this class (see <sup>#</sup>)
3. A default constructor (constructor that has no arguments) is *automatically* created if you don't write your own constructor. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more information - There is no answer better than the tutorial.
4. When you need to initialize the state of a new Object, you need a constructor. Refer to the examples in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to better understand this.

Answer (score 1):

1. The instance variables are placed outside of methods as they shall be available to the whole object/instance. Placing variable inside a method makes them a local variable, which makes it only accessible from inside the method. So when multiple methods try to access the same value, an instance variable is usually first choice.
2. As you already passed the text to the instance via the constructor your printText-method doesn't need any parameters anymore. As the text is stored in an instance variable it can simply access it at a later time (when printText is called).
3. Yes, a constructor is needed in a class. This does not mean that you have to code it yourself. If you do not code a constructor, a default constructor will be inserted automatically that looks like this:

> public HelloWorld() { super(); }
>
> I guess you are a little confused about static calls. Static methods call be called even though you don't have an object of the respective class. System.out.println("Hello, World!"); for example is such a static call. Constructors are neccessary to define the way, how objects are created. Therefore they are omnipresent in every class. If you just don't build your own custom constructor that usually means, that no initial stuff must be done during instantiation.
>
> I hope, this can help you somehow. It is definitely hard to understand all the object oriented concepts at first sight and it felt even harder for me to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a question of the scope. You want to be able to access the variable here again: `public void printText()
   {
       System.out.print(textToPrint);
   }`
   this is why you declare it at the beginning and not in the main function.
2. Is just the conclusion of answer number 1: YOu do not need to pass it a variable, because textToPrint is an instance variable

Good Luck with your studies! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here some answers:

1. You don't need to place this variable at all, if you don't want to do so. You can pass them always from one methode to the other.
2. Because it is saved in the variable textToPrint which is avaible during the whole livetime of the objec myObject and alredy set in the constructor. You clould pass it on the call of the methode if you perefer to do so
3. There is a default constructor. If you don't write one, this one will be used.
4. Yes, you can do it simply like you done it in the last example. But i guess the idea of the exercise was to show you the different ways to build your applikation